# Collecting and displaying nginx statistics

Tags: linux, nginx, statistics

I am using http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule for proxying.

Are there any tools that can give me statistics/connection data per server entry?

Comment: Do you need something more than http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpStubStatusModule ?

Comment: I made the mistaking of thinking that wasn't per server section ! thanks ! yes I did know of it.

Comment: Peter - feel free to answer - I will accept your answer for the points if you like !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the statistics module:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpStubStatusModule

(just adding as answer instead of comment)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but maybe somebody is still interested in the question and answer. I've created a small patch which gather information about all web domains, which are served by nginx (including proxied ones). The disadvantage: you will have to compile nginx from sources, though it is not that hard, since nginx is light-weight and has not that many of dependencies plus `apt-get build-dep nginx` (on Ubuntu/Debian) always helps.

Patch is here: https://github.com/sliusar/nginx-online-stats